# How to check whether a element from given list is in text or not using python?

Tags: python

I have to check whether a element from given list is in text or not,if it is a single word i can,but if it contains multiple words  like below i am not able to get

```
text="what is the price of wheat and White Pepper?"

words=['wheat','White Pepper','rice','pepper']

Expected output=['wheat','White Pepper']
```

I tried in below ways ,but not getting expected output,can anyone help me?

```
>>> output=[word for word in words if word in text]

>>> print output

>>> ['rice', 'White Pepper', 'wheat']
```

here it is taking word "rice" from word "price"

If i use nltk or any it will split "White Pepper" into "White" and "pepper"

```
>>> from nltk import word_tokenize

>>> n_words=word_tokenize(text)

>>> print n_words

>>> ['what', 'is', 'the', 'price', 'of', 'wheat', 'and', 'White', 'Pepper', '?']

>>> output=[word for word in words if word in n_words]
>>> print output

>>> ['wheat']
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use regular expressions and word boundaries:

```
import re

text="what is the price of wheat and White Pepper?"

words=['wheat','White Pepper','rice','pepper']

output=[word for word in words if re.search(r"\b{}\b".format(word),text)]

print(output)
```

result:

```
['wheat', 'White Pepper']
```

you can optimize the search by pre-building your regex (courtesy [Jon Clements](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1252759/jon-clements)):

```
output = re.findall(r'\b|\b'.join(sorted(words, key=len, reverse=True)), text)
```

The sort is necessary to make sure longest strings are taken first. Regex escaping is probably not necessary since the words contain only spaces and alphanums.

Comment: Why search the string multiple times? Something like: `re.findall(r'\b|\b'.join(sorted(words, key=len, reverse=True)), text)
` will give you what you want... (note the sort is necessary to make sure longest strings match first - and you'll probably want to `re.escape` each item in words but I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader) :p

Comment: that sure looks nice. I don't want to copy your answer, you should post that yourself.

Comment: Meh... you know I'm not bothered about that kind of stuff... it's a natural extension to your answer here anyway... feel free to use it.

Comment: Umm... thinking about it... `r'\b{}\b'.format(sorted(...))` will be better.. else the longest string won't need to start on a word boundary...

Comment: Thanks to you both for your answers...@Jean-François Fabre and @Jon Clements

Answer (score 0):

So I would do something like this.

```
def findWord(list, text):
    words = []
    for i in list:
        index = text.find(i) 
        if index != -1:
            if index != 0 and text[index - 1] != " ":
                continue 
            words.append(i)
    return words
```

The find function for string will return -1 if a string is not present. White Pepper returns 31 because that is the index where it starts.

This returns `['wheat', and 'White Pepper']` for the test case you provided.

Comment: Thank you @Austin Stehling...for ur solution